# python3 var inside the same function with same name is different

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4

let's make it short

here's the code, I have class of WorldState and Action, Action class attribute NAME is used here, WorldState discontentment and next_action method is also used

```
def choose_action_plan(max_depth):
# storage for world stage and action
states = [[WorldState(goals, actions, costs), Action('base')]]

# keep track of current best actions
best_action = None
best_value = 10000
best_plan = []

verbose = True

if verbose:
    print('Searching...')

changed = True

while states:
    current_value = states[-1][0].discontentment()

    if verbose and changed:
        print(states[-1][1].name + ' [' + str(current_value) + ']')

    if len(states) >= max_depth:
        # if current value is best (low) keep it!
        if current_value < best_value:
            best_action = states[1][1]
            best_value = current_value
            best_plan = [state[1].name for state in states if state[1]] + [best_value]
        states.pop()
        continue

    next_action = states[-1][0].next_action()
    if next_action:
        new_state = deepcopy(states[-1][0])
        states.append([new_state, None])
        states[-1][1] = Action(next_action)
        # apply action
        new_state.apply_action(next_action)
        changed = True
    else:
        # drop back down a level
        states.pop()


# Return the "best action"
return best_action.name
```

I'm creating a goal oriented action planning for AI,
in the code above `best_action` always returns as a none, I already tried to debug and it pass out through inside of the loop where `best_action` is already filled, and `best_value + best_plan` is not modified either, it's like having 2 different variables outside and within the loop. I don't understand what happened in the code, what did I miss?

Comment: Have you tried making a deepcopy of states and looping over that instead of modifying the original states while looping over it?

Comment: @JacobIRR I didn't actually, I just did a deep copy of WorldState class and append in to the states list so that I have another WorldState that doesn't affect the real one. also I didn't do anything to the best_value, best_action variables at all. python detects both of the variables as 2 different var (I can see it as pycharm gives grey color to the variable)

Comment: ah ok. Now, what is this `best_plan` variable for ?

Comment: @JacobIRR best_action is the next step, while best plan contains plenty of steps ahead for the future.. so it doesn't only see 1 step ahead, if the discontentment for the action ahead can result the lowest one than it will choose the best one

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that my best Action returns none in the last loop (obviously I can't find best action all the time) when the energy is depleted. I only need to check whether `BestAction` is `None` or not before I return it.